Flutter Proxy issue
Building a Flutter application is giving me trouble in the Windows proxy settings. Even though I've already set up my settings exactly like on Android, Flutter is still giving me errors. When i click on Check connection is shows connection successfully. But when i try to build an application in android studio it shows an error. i have already attached an image of it.
Image 1:
https://i.sstatic.net/3GWPd3el.png
Image 2:
https://i.sstatic.net/0kmUHZnC.png
Image 3:
https://i.sstatic.net/gcNzNHIz.png
how to configured proxy settings for flutter in windows and android studio also.

can you run  this comm and in th terminal once after it opens up and see if this works. set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy_userid:proxy_password@proxy_ip:proxy_port then also set HTTPS_PROXY=%HTTP_PROXY%. Customize it with your needs. Actually the command line sometimes not follows the windows proxy. If this works then there is a fix you can do.
